# Sitecore persolization based on time

Tags: sitecore, rule-engine, sitecore-mvc, personalization

I am trying to personalize the sitecore content based on the server time.

I want to show a different content when the server time is between 7 PM to 8 PM.

I have tried it with Date field using the below rule and able to personalize the content based on dates:

```
where date [FieldName,,Enter Field Name,select Date] field [operatorid,Operator,,compares to] [Value,DateTime,,date]
```

But I want to know if I can do it with the Time field as well.

Comment: You should show what you tried so far.

Comment: Worth reading https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/custom-rules-and-conditions-for-sitecore-personalization/ creating a custom rule. It doesn't look like out the box that rule above is supported.

Answer (score 0):

To accept the time range write a custom rule like below,

```
Where Server time is between [TimeMinValue,Integer,,Minimum time] and  [TimeMaxValue,Integer,,Maximum time]
```

And check if the current server time is under selected time range in the custom rule code,

[Created custom rule item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmOXF.png)

[Used custom rule in personalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUGCy.png)